# How to make Mozilla Firefox to follow the Freedesktop XDG specification?

Tags: arch-linux, firefox, xdg

I want to use the **XDG** specification to avoid cluttering in my *$HOME* directory in Arch Linux.

Right now, Firefox version 101 created a **$HOME/.mozilla** directory, which I want to place somewhere else.

So, how can I configure Firefox to use a different directory?

Answer (score 1):

You've got two options

- You can either patch the sources and compile
- Or put this directory anywhere you want and symlink to it, e.g.

```
mkdir ~/.config/mozilla
ln -s ~/.config/mozilla ~/.mozilla
```

---

There's probably a third option which is

`firefox --profile <path>   Start with profile at <path>` however I'm not entirely sure how and whether it works. You can create a shell alias or a `.desktop` file which launches Firefox with this option.

Answer (score 0):

I am not necessarily sure it answers your question, but [waterfox](https://github.com/WaterfoxCo/Waterfox/issues/2345) supports XDG. Waterfox is a fork of firefox, here are more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfox

Comment: This answer is probably better suited as a comment.